# Writing Style Changed

Tags: style, creative-writing, writers-block

After the death of my cousin I have stopped writing for quite some time. However the stories ideas would persist in my mind. So I decided to try and write again, but whatever ideas I have. Turn into tangents or worse, become depressing. 
I have been trying to rewrite a story (the original, was deleted) but whenever I try to, it's like... I used to describe my desire to write with, "I write because I cannot breathe" but now my writing seems stunted. The words don't flow, they muddle and any ideas I have seem fine for one sentence, but when written or combined together with another. They become fake or seem too eager.

How do I write again?

Comment: The question here is unclear, and would probably be fine on a conventional discussion forum. Questions here need to be more specific and answerable; please see out site [tour]. If you want to edit and reopen, comment here and we'll talk about it.

Comment: felt a bit awkward to my eyes. Didn't mean anything more grandiose than that.

Comment: @Bob I disagree with [what's comment](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/17340/writing-style-changed#comment27404_17340) on this; questions that are easier to read are more likely to be answered. While this question has issues with its content, edits for flow and readability are valued as well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that whatever problem you have with writing is not about writing but about how you feel about yourself and your life.

You might want to take a break from writing and try to come to terms with the death of your cousin first. Or you can try to take the pressure out of your writing and write without any concerns for quality and just to relax and have fun with the storytelling. With time your comfort with writing will grow, and you'll find your voice again (or a new voice).

Whatever you do, accept that you have had an experience that is changing you, and that you'll need time to complete that change.

All the best.

Comment: It sounds like a version of writers block. Mixed almost with an A.D.D. sort of issue. Where you can think of things to write, but cant concentrate on them enough to link them to other concepts and ideas.

try meditation, or some other method by which to clear your mind. Imagine nagging thoughts as a little floating leaf or toy boat, that you gently and lovingly place in a soothing but quick river, and "watch" as it gets carried on down the stream to where it is eventually out of site. Visualization usually helps me clear my head. Also, just force yourself to write, i suspect that you are just

Comment: out of practice. and if you can just push through some awkward pages. you will likely find the groove again. Find a way to use your cousins transition and how it affected you, to fuel your creativity, not stifle it. (feels like that is how your cousin would likely have wanted it.)

Comment: @Bob Why don't you post your answer as an answer, instead of a comment to another answer?

Comment: can't downvote a comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a break is a good idea, looking out for signs of depression is another, but if you want to write, try writing in a genre for which you normally have no interest, or for which you even have disdain. The purpose of this would be to remove the pressure of your own expectations. You can practice and noodle around knee-deep in tropes and adverbs and nobody will care.

Sorry if this is a bit flippant or pop-psych but you say you're trying to rewrite an old story. If you were a character in somebody else's, it would be obvious to the reader that you're trying to turn back the clock and relive happier times. I'm sure the truth is more complicated, but for certain you are a different person now, so try something different.

I don't normally like the horror genre but I've dabbled with writing it just when those Lovecraftian adverbs kept rising to the fore. Try writing something depressing. See how dark you can go. One of my favourite authors, Michael Marshall, writes thrillers that turn so bleak I want to find his phone number and ask if he's okay. But black humour breaks through in his text so maybe he gets some release through that process.